Align text to curve line and camera rotation
I am looking for  a solution where my text is aligned to the camera and rotated to be aligned with a curve line or mesh line in 3D space. It is part of a technical dimensions system I am working on.


If I understand correctly, you're getting the alignment to the camera and you want to rotate the text along the local z-axis ?

yes exacly, to line up with the curve line.
